# Hiding some of Intellij debugger and editor toolbars to reduce screen clutter

Tags: intellij-idea

From this shot we can see *four* bars / toolbars of various sizes associated with debugging and an editor panel:

[image]

At the least I would like to remove /reclaim the real estate from the first one:

[image]

and the last one:

[image]

In addition it would be preferable to *reduce the height* of the two middle toolbars

[image]

Are any of these adjustments possible ?  I am using `Intellij 2018.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Breadcrumbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93LD6.png) can be disabled in the IDE settings. I don't think you can do anything with the other toolbars. Request is [welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).